# Create Bootstrap-Token without kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I would like to create a Bootstrap-Token to add a new node to the cluster. We are using a hosted kubernetes cluster and do not have any access to kubeadm, just to kubectl.

Is it possible to create a Bootstrap-Token and add a server as a node only with kubectl?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet-tls-bootstrapping/) it's possible to perform TLS bootstrapping of kubelet in a worker node and join the worker node to the kubernetes cluster. This process is automated in kubeadm. You need to have access to the certificate authority `ca.key` and `ca.pem` used on the master nodes and use those to generate certificates. But in a hosted kubernetes cluster you probably don't have access to the certificate authority.

Comment: Thanks, I have access to download the X.509 certificate, which contains `ca.crt` , `client.crt`, `client.key` . It should provide access to the cluster. How do I proceed?

Comment: the medium article is using kubeadm to create the token, but I can't use it.

Comment: Okay the official doc is the only resource I could find